# Can we upgrade the unicorns to something more ... predatory

Tags: discussion, status-declined, unicorns

Nothing against unicorns of course, they are great ... but can we upgrade the meta mascot to something more ... majestic? I mean, am I the only one who is not a fan of something that looks like a donkey and eats only grass?

---

Also, on the issue of whether unicorns are real ...

[image]

Comment: does meta has mascot ??

Comment: **SO MUCH RAGE**

Comment: What end are you looking at?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting rid of unicorns.

Comment: P.s. Its not exactly official so you can't really "change" it. I mean **RAGE**

Comment: Why the downvotes, seriously why? evil unicorns ... really? How evil can a single horned pony be, what can it do? Bump your butt using its horn?

Comment: Its because [shadhahvar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadhavar) is too hard to spell.

Comment: @telkitty.exe The downvotes are mostly in jest, people are very protective of unicorns round here

Comment: @RichardTingle Jest!  Unicorns are serious business!

Comment: I feel like @BoltClock may be slightly biased here.

Comment: unf ... bounty in 2 days ... can hardly wait!

Comment: @BoltClock It'd be nice if you took the advice of [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229070/moderators-please-make-reasons-easier-to-understand-when-setting-status-declined) to provide a more constructive revision note when adding a status declined flag.  It would have been nice if you had taken the time to write out `status-declined because "unicorns"`.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks, done.

Comment: @Servy: I know. I did change it to something else, however.

Comment: Unicorns ARE predatory. Once they lull you into a false sense of safety with their pony-eyes and tails and magic rainbows they GORE YOU TO DEATH WITH THEIR MIGHTY HORN AND EAT YOUR ENTRAILS! (Yah, you're never gonna look at that unicorn the same way again, are you? You're welcome!)

Comment: I may be a Unitato, but due to my species' relation to Unicorns, I cannot support this proposal. At all.

Comment: Can we upgrade the unicorns to something more … potato-y? @Andrew'saUnitato

Comment: @Bart We could stick potatoes on their horns.

Comment: By the way, *Trogdor and the Unicorns* would be an awesome name for a rock band.

Answer (score 28):

We already have something more predatory:

[image]

Unicorns are necessary in order to soften it.

Comment: What the heck is it? An eel with 2 ill positioned fins, 2 sticks and a single arm?

Comment: @telkitty, don't ask me. I don't want to make it angrier.

Comment: @telkitty.exe You do not know of [trogdor the burninator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gz1DIIxmEE)!!!

Comment: @telkitty.exe Trogdor was a man. No wait he was a dragon man. Or maybe he was just a dragon. But he was still TROGDOR!

Comment: the eel is seriously making me hungry ...

Comment: @telkitty, do you fancy a wing or a leg?

Comment: Are you trying to fool me, I don't want a wing or a leg, I want the fish ... also try to NOT make any food as the meta mascot, I don't want to pile on weight everytime I come onto meta ...

Comment: Is that the "Giant S" from the old "pluralization bug" Jeff answer?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, yes. It has mutated a little.

Answer (score 6):

Who says unicorns aren't predatory? Here is an [artist's rendition](http://devin-mcgrath.com/Unicorn-Destroyer-of-Ponies).

Comment: Hey, that's BoltClock in the close review queue!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predation & http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/predatory ... get the definition right, kid.

Comment: @telkitty.exe I don't see a single mention of "unicorn" in that wikipedia article. And please, don't feed me that tired old line that unicorns aren't real; even a 6-year-old can tell you they are.

Comment: Am I not evidence enough that they're real? Jeez, you humans (and um, telkitties) are weird.

Comment: The artist's rendition is an error 404.